# How do I make a Bounce like animation with CSS?

Tags: html, css, animation

So when the page loads in, I would like my set containers to bounce in. For example, the CSS should be...

```
.bouncein {
  animation-name: bounceIn;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-delay: 0.5s;`
}
```

but I need to know the key frames.

So when the page loads, my div's with class bouncein will bounce in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this 
also for more css animations 
check this https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/

for delay u can use "animation-delay"
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-delay.asp

like: 
animation: bounceIn 2s infinite 2s;

```css
@keyframes bounceIn {
 0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {
    transform: translateY(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
 40% {
    transform: translateY(-30px);
  }
 60% {
    transform: translateY(-15px);
  }
}


body {
  background: black;
}

.arrow {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left:-20px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
  background-size: contain;
  opacity: 0;
}

.bounce {
  animation: bounceIn 2s infinite 2s;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow bounce"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks that worked but I want it to bounce in when the page loads and have a delay. So after 5 seconds it will pop up and it will be seen.

Comment: Yes I know about that but I want it as a transition. So before the delay it is transparent and after the delay, it become seen again. So there for a transition.

Comment: @SimonMitchell so what is the problem? just add opacity: 0; by defauld and opacity: 1; when u need. answer updated

Comment: My code is 

 `opacity: 0;
 -webkit-animation:rollIn;
 -moz-animation:rollIn;
 animation:rollIn;
 
 -webkit-animation-delay: 3s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 3s;
    animation-delay: 3s;
 
    -webkit-animation-duration:1s;
    -moz-animation-duration:1s;
    animation-duration:1s;`

But this happens: [link](https://gyazo.com/d66cef697b913bad777d815f3d8e1322)

After the animation, the object goes invisible again

Comment: What happens is after the animation has finished, it goes invisible again. I don't want it going infinate like that arrow is doing. That is why it isn't disapparing.

Comment: in this case u can simply use "animation-fill-mode" like here http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_animation-fill-mode

Comment: Oh yes I did try this before I asked the question but it didn't work. Don't know what I did wrong but it works now. Thank you so much :)

Comment: @SimonMitchell np) to say thanks you can simply mark my answer as solved (:

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like that:

```css
.bouncein {
  animation-name: bounceIn;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

@keyframes bounceIn {
0% {
 transform:translateY(-100%);
 opacity: 0;
}
15% {
  transform:translateY(0);
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
30% {
  transform:translateY(-50%);
}
40% {
   transform:translateY(0%);
    padding-bottom: 6px;
}
50% {
  transform:translateY(-30%);
}
}
70% {
    transform:translateY(0%);
    padding-bottom: 7px;
}
80% {
  transform:translateY(-15%);
}
90% {
  transform:translateY(0%);
  padding-bottom: 8px;
}
95% {
  transform:translateY(-7%);
}
97% {
  transform:translateY(0%);
  padding-bottom: 9px;
}
99% {
  transform:translateY(-3%);
}
100% {
  transform:translateY(0);
  padding-bottom: 9px;
  opacity: 1;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="bouncein"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

the answer showed by Arkej works, but I think it's easier and better to use Animate.CSS instead.

Comment: I agree with you ^^

Comment: If you wanted just a simple bounce.  Why use a huge css addon?